# What are some titles of math textbooks for schoolchildren with critical race theory?

Tags: reference-request

They say that Florida just rejected several math textbooks with prohibited topics like critical race theory. This is got to be for real, because they said publishers can appeal the rejection. What are the titles of some of those rejected books? Or of any math textbook with critical race theory? Asking for a friend who has school age children.

Comment: lmaoooooooooooo

Comment: There are apparently $54$ such books in Florida, their titles are not known to the public.

Comment: https://www.amazon.com/Critical-Race-Theory-Mathematics-Education/dp/113856267X/ref=sr_1_1?keywords=critical+race+theory+in+mathematics+education&qid=1650242061&sprefix=critical+race+theory+mathe%2Caps%2C168&sr=8-1 There is a short and good review of that book at Amazon: "What a load of crap".

Comment: Published details of what happened in Florida seem to be at https://www.fldoe.org/academics/standards/instructional-materials/ so you may have to do things like comparing https://www.fldoe.org/core/fileparse.php/5574/urlt/2021-22-Short-Bid-report-Final-xlsx.pdf and https://www.fldoe.org/core/fileparse.php/5574/urlt/2122MathAdoptedMaterials.pdf - though note that one of the reasons given for rejection is inclusion of "Common Core"

Comment: @Henry: Can you give **one** example of a math text for K-12 containing CRT? Your link points to a 100-page document where it is hard to find anything related to math.

Comment: @markvs That is not what I was trying to do.  My second link gives the 132 books bid and the second link the adopted materials.  For example, there are 5 books in the bid list with *stats* or *statistics* in the title, 1 of which is in the adopted list.  So *Elementary Statistics* was adopted while *Statistics and Probability with Applications* and *Stats: Modeling the World* and *Stats In Your World* and *Elementary Statistics: Picturing the World* were not - it does not explain why not.

Comment: More worrying to me than any political posturing, is the price of the books shown for example in https://www.fldoe.org/core/fileparse.php/5574/urlt/9-12math.pdf which look many times what I would expect for similar books in the UK such as those in https://www.cgpbooks.co.uk/secondary-books/gcse/maths

Comment: @Henry The UK books are exam revision guides and practice workbooks. The Florida materials have labels such as "Major Tool Package Component" with different prices for 1, 2, 3, 4, or 5 years. I don't think these are comparable purchases at all. Not that I doubt the basic premise: at least for university-level textbooks, publishers charge much more in the US than just about anywhere else.

Comment: A [full 608 page printed textbook for the main UK two-year mathematics course](https://www.cgpbooks.co.uk/secondary-books/gcse/maths/mxht42-grade-9-1-gcse-maths-edexcel-student) including personal online access to all text costs £20 ($26) - you can buy exam revision materials on top if you wish, but it is not expected as most students instead finally prepare by doing previous papers